# Does Not Conform To Protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' Error?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to set up my table view, I am using

```
class ExerciseDatabaseController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

I am then using the mandatory functions:

```
func ExerciseDatabaseController(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    return cell
}
```

and

```
func ExerciseDatabaseController(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

as per the apple guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

I cant work out why I am still having non conforming protocol errors for this class?

> Type 'ExerciseDatabaseController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: Why are you prepending your class name to them though? You are creating new methods that kinda look like the ones the protocol is search for, but they aren't.

Comment: Sorry this is the first time ive done this so probably making stupid mistakes, the error is that ive given the functions the prepended name of the class? I must have misread the tutorial!

Comment: Simply look at the documentation for `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` for the proper declaration of these functions.

Comment: See [`numberOfRowsInSection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview) and [`cellForRowAt`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview) for information on what the method signatures must look like. As ohr said, you don't want your class name as part of the method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start typing the name of the functions Xcode will auto-complete them for you. Here's an example that'll [help](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) you. (And doc. in the link)

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
```